# From python's ggplot: ImportError: cannot import name load_world

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, importerror, python-ggplot

I try to install ggplot for Python 2 in anaconda with `conda install -c conda-forge ggplot` for `Python 2.7.13 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.`, but when I try to `from ggplot import *` I get the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name load_world
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error steps from an old version of ggplot. Install the newest version with

```
conda install -c conda-forge ggplot=0.11.5
conda install -c conda-forge brewer2mpl=1.4.1
```

It might be required to install `brewer2mpl` additionally and possibly to reinstall

```
conda install pyqt
```